# How to make while loop a function in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, probability

I created a While Loop that works perfectly fine on its own. However, once I try to store it as a function, it no longer works. Below is a simple example of my problem.

```
import random
money = 100
bet = 0

while bet < 10:
  outcome = random.randint(0,1)
  bet = bet + 1

  if outcome == 1:
    money = money + 10

  if outcome == 0:
    money = money - 10
  
money
```

Here is my attempt to store it as a function. The output only runs one bet and not all 10.

```
def loop():
  money = 100
  bet = 0
  
  while bet < 10:
    outcome = random.randint(0,1)
    bet = bet + 1

    if outcome == 1:
      money = money + 10

    if outcome == 0:
      money = money - 10


    return money
```

Comment: You have return in your while loop, meaning after 1 iteration the function will always return 'money' and therefore stop

Answer (score 1):

You make a simple mistake with an indent - your `return` is in `while` loop, so it returns after first iteration. Move it back a bit ;)

```
def loop():
  money = 100
  bet = 0
  
  while bet < 10:
    outcome = random.randint(0,1)
    bet = bet + 1

    if outcome == 1:
      money = money + 10

    if outcome == 0:
      money = money - 10

  return money
```

Comment: A mistake this simple is really a typo. I'd like you to vote to close as such.

Comment: Ahhh great catch. This is correct!

Comment: As you wish @quamrana